# How to define a mesh?

Tags: python, game-engine

For defining objects, the usual `scene.objects["obj"]` works. I am trying to do the same concept but with a mesh. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my previous answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43915/calling-properties-of-objects-in-python-only-works-for-current-scene-even-when-o), you want to get the mesh (one of them), not define it. To do that you should use `obj.meshes[0]` (since usually there is only one mesh).

You can find the BGE API [here](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/contents.html). Of particular interest is the [KX_GameObject](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html) class, where most of BGE coding is actually done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, will it work if I define this: obj.meshes[0]? You stated to call it, not define it. If I will use it a whole lot, will it be fine if I define it or will it just not work? And how can an object have 2 meshes? If I change the mesh of an object, does that mean there is a new mesh?

Comment: An object can have a display mesh and a physics mesh. But this is not what it provides. KX_GameObject.meshes provides display meshes only. I never saw an object with more than one mesh.

Comment: You can store the mesh in a variable for local use (mesh = object.meshes[0]). But I strongly advice to avoid to store context data (such as current scene, current controller, current object and current objects mesh) outside the context (e.g. at module level or a property of another object). This will result in hard to investigate side-effects.